# What does ArrayList without any generic type set mean and do?

Tags: java, generics

I noticed that it's possible to define a variable like this, without specifying it's generic type.
While this seems to compile, I noticed some strange issues when I did it to more complicated classes, such as no longer picking up method signatures properly. These problems went away when I used a  insted of just leaving off the generic type.

Is there any practical purpose to the below code, and what is the difference between it and using `ArrayList<?>` instead?

```
Class Example {
  private ArrayList list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw typed collections are maintained for compatibility reasons with pre-generics Java versions (i.e. < 5).

Their usage is discouraged unless there is compatibility issue.

A non-generic `ArrayList` is like an `ArrayList<Object>` without any type safety.

Due to type erasure, method signatures do not retain parametrized generic types, so this is usually a source of confusion when overloading methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed for backwards compatibility, prior to Java 5 generics didn't exist and when they added them they didn't want to break existing code.

Most compilers/IDEs will give you a warning but conceptually it's the same as doing `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

A generic class can have multiple type parameters

look here for more info and examples...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html